# Android POST has empty response

Tags: android

I'm sending a post request to http://www.pgu.donland.ru/php/Login.php using HttpClient and want to get response like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><resp status="1" uD="John" UID="2" e=""/>
```

but unfortunately I keep getting:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resp status="1" uD="" UID="" e=""/>`

What is happening here?

I'm using a custom class with HttpClient client field in it and in my constructor I'm using these settings:

```
SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
    schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
                                    .getSocketFactory(), 80));
    schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", new EasySSLSocketFactory(),
                                    443));

    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    params.setParameter(ConnManagerPNames.MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS, 30);
    params.setParameter(ConnManagerPNames.MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_ROUTE,
                                    new ConnPerRouteBean(30));
    params.setParameter(HttpProtocolParams.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
    params.setParameter("http.socket.timeout", timeout * 1000);
    params.setParameter("http.connection.timeout", timeout * 1000);
    // params.setParameter("http.connection-manager.timeout", new
    // Long(timeout * 1000));
    params.setParameter("http.protocol.head-body-timeout", timeout * 1000);
    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

    ClientConnectionManager cm = new SingleClientConnManager(params,
                                    schemeRegistry);
    this.client = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params);
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

a problem is on the server side. Check Login.php code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Russian is not the easiest language for an italian but... It looks like the uD and UID parameters are echoed by the server after having received them as a user name/password (or a user key) from the client. Maybe you are not sending any userID or any username/password pair to the server so it cannot respond you in the expected way.

Comment: I'm send valid username and pass

Comment: Then the problem is on the server, for sure.